# Error in UseMethod("do_"): no applicable method for 'do_' applied to an object of class "c('double','numeric')"?

Tags: r

apologies as there really isn't much to go off here, I've been sent a screenshot of an error by a friend, I'm happy to go and get more information but wasn't sure if anyone in here could help me out with an answer based off the info I have currently :)

> Sample1 = do(200)*mean(resample(BIRTH$Bweight,10))
>
> Error in UseMethod("do_"): 
>     no applicable method for 'do_' applied to an object of class 
>       "c('double','numeric')"

Apologies again if there's a clear lack of usable info here, R isn't my strong suit by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Maybe they mean `Sample1 = do( 200 * mean(resample(BIRTH$Bweight,10)) )`?